# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference (Crash on button click)

Tags: java, android

hi am currently new to android studio and i have encounter this problem where am totally stuck and i have no ideal on how to solve the problem the app works fine just that when i click on convert button it crashes   , Please help

The error i got

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.wxy.sg_cheapskate.MainActivity.onConvertButtonClicked(MainActivity.java:85)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Xml for the app

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.wxy.sg_cheapskate.converterActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Currency Converter"
    android:id="@+id/CurrencyConverter"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="139dp"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/NumberEditText"
    android:hint="Enter Value!"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CurrencyConverter"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="25dp"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/NumberEditText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="USD TO SGD"
        android:id="@+id/Ustosg"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RINGGIT TO SGD"
        android:id="@+id/Mytosg"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YUAN TO SGD"
        android:id="@+id/prctosg"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="EURO TO SGD"
        android:id="@+id/eutosg"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="YEN TO SGD"
        android:id="@+id/japtosg"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Convert"
    android:id="@+id/convertBtn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="onConvertButtonClicked"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
```

Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {





SectionPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

static final String LOG_TAG = "SlidingTabsBasicFragment";

private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private NavigationView mDrawer;
private EditText Number;
private RadioButton usd2sgd;
private RadioButton ringgit2sgd;
private RadioButton yuan2sgd;
private RadioButton euro2sgd;
private RadioButton yen2sgd;




protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer);
    mDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            mDrawerLayout,
            mToolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    Number = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.NumberEditText);
    usd2sgd = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Ustosg);
    ringgit2sgd = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Mytosg);
    yuan2sgd = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.prctosg);
    euro2sgd = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.eutosg);
    yen2sgd = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.japtosg);
}

public void onConvertButtonClicked (View v) {
    double value = new Double(Number.getText().toString());

    if (usd2sgd.isChecked())
            value = ConvertMoney.UsTosg(value);
    if (ringgit2sgd.isChecked())
        value = ConvertMoney.MyTosg(value);
    if (yuan2sgd.isChecked())
        value = ConvertMoney.PrcTosg(value);
    if (euro2sgd.isChecked())
        value = ConvertMoney.EuTosg(value);
    if (yen2sgd.isChecked())
        value = ConvertMoney.JapTosg(value);
    Number.setText(new Double(value).toString());

}
```

Comment: `Number` is a class in Java, you shouldn't use it as a variable name. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Comment: hmmmm i changed the variable name and it still crashes D:

Comment: and the error it's some thing to do with this line under java                   double value = new Double(Number.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0):

Firstly focus on Lee's comment.

Second, cast `String` to `double` like this :

```
double value = Double.parseDouble("Double string here");
```

Comment: uhh what do u mean by ("Double string here"); i dont rlly get it ._.

Comment: like `Double.parseDouble("3.1428");`

Comment: sooo for my case is it Double value = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString())); ??

Comment: Exactly. Though, you should first check that if `input.getText().toString()` is null or empty so that you don't get a `NPE`.

Comment: err how do i check wether is my input.getText().toString() us null or empty ?? srry for the question am totally new to android

Comment: Looks like you are new to Java too. Anyway, do this `if("".equalsIgnoreCase(input.getText().toString())`, this will avoid NPE and also check for empty string. Do accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: am i suppose to put anything in the " " ??

Comment: No. Not even a space.

Answer (score 0):

What Shubham is trying to say is rename your variable `Number` to something else, let's say `num` then change every occurrence of `Number` to `num`. Reason being, Number is a java class and cannot be used as a variable name.

```
num= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NumberEditText);
...
double value = Double.parseDouble(num.getText());
...
num.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

Comment: i changed the variable Number to input aready but the app still crashes went i clicked on the button here's the edited java code http://paste.ofcode.org/5rTF4CrATe2H4eFgmhNEPK

Comment: Is that the entire file? I don't see where you assign the listener to the button.

Comment: this the the entire java code please take a look http://paste.ofcode.org/T9e9L7vrLCicuKGEd4hXCF

Comment: You never call the method 'onConvertButtonClicked()' so you cannot expect that portion of the code to run until you call that method.

Answer (score 0):

That exception is exclusively thrown if you're using an object without initializing it.  Check whether you've correctly initialized the Number object.  You could check whether Number is initialized or not by doing :

```
if(Number!=null){
        //stuff here
    }
```

Comment: where should i put it o.o? onclick?

Comment: Put it anywhere before calling the setText() method,  it's just for checking whether Number is null or not.(which I think it is)

Comment: What do you mean by nth?

Comment: the app still crashes

Comment: That's what I suspected.  That means Number isn't initialized.  Check your code again to ensure Number is properly initialized

Comment: Just a quick thought,  clean and build your project.

Comment: uhh do u mind if u sent you the file? and take a look at it cus is very hard for me to explain anything as am very new to android studio

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that and by the way the solution is right there and the problem isn't about being new to Android Studio.  Give a try to Clean Building your project or restarting Android Studio. Sometimes the IDE doesn't inflate widgets from the xml file.

Comment: hmm i did a clean project and rebuilding it ,its the same result

Comment: Do you get the same Exception that you were getting at the beginning?  Post latest stack

Comment: u mean logcat if it is then yes

Comment: The code that I posted,  use that as the first line in your clicked method and do a Log.d to print some message saying that the object isn't null.  Then see the output of logcat.  That way we'll at least be sure that the object is initialized